# Find correct android version on device

Tags: android

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
        //--incompatible code--
    } else {
        //--compatible code--
    }
```

The condition runs into incompatible code on Gingerbread. Does `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` represents actual device version ? or the SDK version the app has been compiled with ?

Comment: Which version would you like to be the cutoff for compatible vs. incompatible code? 2.3? 2.3.3? 3.0?

Comment: its run for me as good. that shows me comptiable. if  i replace gingerbread to eclair then not comptible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a static member, which was assigned value when the app first executes.

```
public static final int SDK_INT = SystemProperties.getInt("ro.build.version.sdk", 0);
```

The SystemProperties.getInt() member function runs on your target device and is not determined when you compile your application.

According to the official guide you should use >= instead of > when detect api version, i.e.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
```

since there may be minor versions between major versions.

Comment: Depends on what breaks the compatibility, if its exclusive to newer API then this approach is useful too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that there are 2 codes for GB:

`Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD` -> API 9

and

`Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1` -> API 10

as `minSdkVersion` API in manifest = 10 then I should have used `Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1`.